# Analytic extension and analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{D}_a\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. And suppose $f$ is analytic, and has an analytic extension to every point of $\partial\mathbb{D}_a$. Then why $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}_b$ for some $b>a$? What methods can we use to see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(edited based on comments)

For any point $w \in \partial\mathbb{D}_a$ there is an $c_w>0$ for which the function is analytic on $\mathbb{D}_a \cup B_w(c_w)$; each small ball $B_w(c_w)$ contains an open set $D_w$ that is "a circular trapezoid" of the form $(1+t)z, z \in C_w, |t| < \delta_w, \delta_w >0$ where $C_w$ is a small open arc of $\partial\mathbb{D}_a$ centered at $w$ and $\delta_w>0$ small enough depending on $c_w$, so $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}_a \cup D_w$ and by analytic continuation, any two such extensions coincide on the intersection of their domains since they coincide on the original open disc.

By compacity of the circle we can choose finitely many $w_1,..w_k$ for which $\cup_{m=1}^k D_{w_m}$ covers $\partial\mathbb{D}_a$, hence in particular the union of the arcs $C_{w_k}$ is $\partial\mathbb{D}_a$, so if $\delta =\min_{m=1}^k \delta_{w_m} >0$ the function is analytic on $\mathbb{D}_{a+\delta}$ since for any point $y \in  \mathbb{D}_{a+\delta}$, either $y \in \mathbb{D}_a$ or $y$ is in one of the "circular trapezoids" $(1+t)z, z \in C_{w_m}, 0 \le t < \delta_{w_m}$ where we take the index $m$ one of such for which the line joining $y$ and the center of the circle intersects the open arc $C_{w_m}$ (which exists because those arcs cover the circle)

Comment: Small quibble: you have to show that the extensions to different $\mathbb D_a \cup B_w(\delta_w)$ agree on their intersection.

Comment: @paul edited based on comments